# How can I fetch two sets of results in a single MySQL query from the same table?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a MySQL table of comments, like this:

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| userid     | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| comment    | char(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| content    | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| ratings    | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| datetime   | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ip         | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_updated | tinyint(2)       | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| record_num | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now I can fetch comments from this and usernames from another table using an `INNER JOIN` query like this.

I can get the top the three comments ORDER BY comments.ratings DESC:

```
SELECT comments.userid, users.username, comments.comment, comments.ratings, comments.datetime, comments.record_num , content.uploader , content.anonymous
FROM comments
LEFT JOIN users ON  comments.userid = users.record_num
LEFT JOIN content ON comments.content = content.record_num
WHERE comments.content = ? ORDER BY comments.ratings DESC limit 3
```

and

#### Getting regular comments ORDER BY comments.datetime DESC

```
SELECT comments.userid, users.username, comments.comment, comments.ratings, comments.datetime, comments.record_num , content.uploader , content.anonymous
FROM comments
LEFT JOIN users ON  comments.userid = users.record_num
LEFT JOIN content ON comments.content = content.record_num
WHERE comments.content = ? ORDER BY comments.datetime DESC limit ?, ?
```

I am trying show users the top three comments by their ratings at first and then regular comments order by comments.datetime DESC .

Now how can I join the above two MySQL queries into one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the other answer says - you can combine results using `union` - which simply means to join two results together.  What is important to note, however, is that you can't simply `union` those two queries together directly, as they use `order by`, so we need to wrap them in outer queries, and use a ranking variable to ensure we can reconstruct the union in the order that we want:

```
select * from (
    SELECT 1 as tbl, 
           comments.userid, 
           users.username, 
           comments.comment, 
           comments.ratings, 
           comments.datetime, 
           comments.record_num, 
           content.uploader, 
           content.anonymous,
           @rank := @rank + 1 as rank
    FROM comments 
      LEFT JOIN users ON  comments.userid = users.record_num 
      LEFT JOIN content ON comments.content = content.record_num
      CROSS JOIN (select @rank := 0 ) q
    WHERE comments.content = ? ORDER BY comments.ratings DESC limit 3
) q1    
UNION ALL
select * from (    
    SELECT 2 as tbl, 
           comments.userid, 
           users.username, 
           comments.comment, 
           comments.ratings, 
           comments.datetime, 
           comments.record_num, 
           content.uploader, 
           content.anonymous,
           @rank := @rank + 1 as rank
    FROM comments 
      LEFT JOIN users ON  comments.userid = users.record_num 
      LEFT JOIN content ON comments.content = content.record_num
      CROSS JOIN (select @rank := 0 ) q
    WHERE comments.content = ? ORDER BY comments.datetime DESC limit ?, ?
) q2
ORDER BY tbl asc, rank asc;
```

`union` by default is `distinct` meaning that it won't duplicate rows found in both result sets, however there is also no guarantee that the rows will be returned in the order you expect, hence the need to mark each table with its own `tbl` value, and then `order by` that field.

If you were certain there would be no duplicates, you could eliminate the duplicate check by using `union all`, instead of `union`

Comment: @AMB they are your two queries - i just formatted them differently for slightly easier reading. There's not much additional work that's gone into it

Comment: is there a way, i can display even duplicate values too , i mean if there are only 3 comments , then it should return 6 comments, first set order by comments.ratings DESC and another set ORDER BY comments.datetime DESC

Comment: there is error in query at the last line , it should be ORDER BY ratings desc, datetime desc

Comment: the `order by tbl` is necessary to ensure your top 3 comments appear first, as `tbl` is what indicates which query it came from

Comment: then something is wrong, as first query is not ordering by comments.ratings DESC , i have tried both queries independently, they work good, but with union all, first query orders by datetime desc

Comment: i've updated the query to use a ranking variable to identify the proper row order. try it now

Comment: results are more weird, cant even figure out the order they are showing in . looks like ratings asc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77064/discussion-between-pala-and-amb).

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, yes you can combine your queries using `UNION`, **but**

> I am trying show users the top three comments by their ratings at first and then regular comments order by comments.datetime DESC

If your are trying to achieve something like the functionality of comments of Stack Overflow, where the top comments (or comments with upvotes) are showed first, then I think **separate queries are** **good enough**.

If your query is combined, then the user is required to **load all the top and regular comments**. Also, it is somehow **hard to make or implement a pagination** with big query that have `UNION` (based on my experience because I'm still a noob on coding).

> Disclaimer: it is *hard*, but not impossible

If I'm the one who is going to code that problem, *first* my program will load the top three comments. After that, there is a 'Show more comments' button that will post to my server using [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) and append the result (regular comments) to the list of showed comments. With that, queries need to be separate like what you have now.

Answer (score 0):

To stack result sets on top of each other into one set, you need to use a "UNION" - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html